# Define a function to get the elements of 2D matrix from user in C

Tags: c, function, matrix

I can't finish this code please help me! I have to matrix, and the program reads items of matrix in function

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{ 
   int r1,c1;
   printf("Enter dimension of first matrix :");
   scanf("%d %d",&r1,&c1);

   int m1[r1][c1];
   GetArray(m1,r1,c1);


   system("PAUSE"); 
   return 0;
}
void GetArray(int arr[][],int _row,int _column)
{
    int i,j,num;
    printf("Enter number: ");
    for(i==0;i<_row;i++){
        for(j==0;j< _column;j++){
           scanf("%d",&num);
           arr[i][j]=num;}} //give error in this line
}
```

Comment: You do realize, that `==` checks for equality and `=` is assignment, which is what you want.

Comment: `int m1[r1][c1];` you see, you can't do this with `r1` and `c1` read from the keyboard. You need to dynamically allocate `m1`. Either that or give m1 fixed sizes larger than what would be input from the keyboard and declare r1 and c1 static const.

Answer (score 1):

In C programming, `==` is used for comparison and `=` is used for assignment operations. You would definitely want to assign values to `j` and `i` in your `for` loops. In your case, you are not initializing the loop variables (when you declare them in the beginning of the function) and since they get garbage values when they are not initialized, you try to reach beyond the bounds of the array you are using in the `for` loops, thus getting a segmentation fault.

Comment: Thanks for answer == is my carelessness. Main problem is i have to initialize second dimension of array in function like
void GetArray(int arr[][3],int _row,int _column)

Comment: oh, i forgot to mention it. Yes you must also specify the 2nd dimension. I'm glad if i could help:)

Answer (score 0):

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{ 
    int r1,c1;
    printf("Enter dimension of first matrix :");
    scanf("%d %d",&r1,&c1);
    int **m1;
    for(int i = 0; i<r1 ;++i) // use c99 !
        m1[i] = malloc(c1* sizeof(int));
    GetArray(m1,r1,c1);
    system("PAUSE");
    for(int i = 0; i<r1 ;++i)
        free(m1[i]);
    return 0;
}
void GetArray(int ** m1,int _row,int _column)
{
    int i,j,num;
    printf("Enter number: ");
    for(i=0;i<_row;i++){
        for(j=0;j< _column;j++){
           scanf("%d",&num);
           m1[i][j]=num;}} //give error in this line
}
```

Untested